# jQuery variable height on list items that change on click

Tags: jquery

So I have:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<a href="#">Click</a>
```

I want to get and add the height of the `<ul>` to itself, so I do:

```
var height = $("ul").height();
$("ul").css("height",height);
```

But then when the `<a>` tag is clicked the list changes to have more, less, or the same number of list-items in it, so in order to add a CSS height transition I would like it to change the CSS height value when the height of the `<ul>` changes. How do I do this? When I try adding on click it uses the old height value, or I have to reset the height value and then re-add which doesn't seem to allow my CSS transition.

**UPDATE**

*Thanks for all your help guys. I've kind of abandoned it as client was happy with a fixed height regardless of number of items. I'm also aware I possibly didn't explain my issue that well. I'll do better next time :)*

Comment: can you please post a jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle height:

```
$('ul').toggle('height')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this css rule to the ul

```
transition:height 0.5s;
```

change 0.5s to the transition time you need

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this. Anyway you have to reset `ul` height each time you append a new `li` element cause if you don't do that `ul` keeps old value.

**js**

```
$("a").on("click", 
          function(){
              $("ul").css("height","");/*Resets height of ul*/
              $("ul").append("<li>Item</li>");/*Append a new li element*/
              var height = $("ul").height();/*find ul height*/
              $("ul").css("height",height);/*Apply new height to ul*/             
          });
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5U39a/3/)

I suggest just to append `li` element to `ul`:

```
$("a").on("click", 
          function(){
              $("ul").append("<li>Item</li>");             
          });
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5U39a/5/)

Comment: You don't need to reassign height as it get calculated automatically. Later solution will do same.

Comment: Exactly. That's why i wrote "i don't know why you want to do this". But i assume maybe he means something like that. Hope he comment and said if he means that or not so i can handle my answer.